# How to write session for both www. and non-www version of my domain?

Tags: php, session

I'm writing session on `mydomain.com/login.php` I believe this can't be accessed in `www.mydomain.com`. Is that right?

How can I write to $_SESSION so I can access it from both the www. and non-www version of my domain?

Comment: Make a permanent 301 redirect from either www to non-www or from non-www to www. It has SEO benefits (?) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) 
it explains setting `.` in the domain will allows for access to subdomains as well,

```
Cookie domain, for example 'www.php.net'. To make cookies visible on all 
subdomains then the domain must be prefixed with a dot like '.php.net'.
```

miki has an example

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#94961

Comment: Its very important to clear all cookies set before testing this change..

Answer (score 0):

**session_set_cookie_params("$lifetime","$path","$domain","$secure","$httponly")** is the best one in php language for setting session in both www and non-www url