# PHP Session lost when switching from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com

Tags: php, session

Hy everyone,

If I visit my website with http://mywebsite.com there is a login page, upon successful login I redirect user to http://www.mywebsite.com instead of http://mywebsite.com.
I noticed that the session has been set but it is lost when switching from http:// to http://www, 
though `setcookie('name', $data, time()+seconds, '/', ".mywebsite.com")`
this work on both http:// and http://www
Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make //mywebbsite.com an alias of //www.mywebsite.com on a lower level (e.g. in .htaccess) instead of doing it in the application.

Comment: @MrLister yes that could be possible :) but why the session is lost?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280994/how-to-write-session-for-both-www-and-non-www-version-of-my-domain/18228118#18228118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [session_set_cookie_params](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set the cookie domain for the session to .mywebsite.com, or save the session id in your own cookies.

But I would suggest to create an redirect to the www or non-www version of your site in the htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however, this solution was good for me, perhaps will help others in the future

edit you php.ini

session.cookie_domain = ".exemple.com"

or in you script php

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');

session_start();

-

-

if you have problems try add this in your php.ini

suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = Off

suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot = Off